# Appcelerator - Crash on Ad-Hoc distribution but ran successfully on device using wired connection

Tags: iphone, crash, titanium, appcelerator, ad-hoc-distribution

This question is related to Appcelerator Titanium development on iPhone.

I was able to run the app on a device directly connected to my mac but the app kept on crashing every time I did ad-hoc distribution.

The crash always happened after the app splash screen popped up.

I also noticed that the app size is larger when installed directly from Titanium Studio to the device using wired connection. And it is smaller when I did ad-hoc distribution then manually installed the distribution IPA through iTunes.

I use iOS 5.1 SDK, Titanium SDK 2.1.1.GA, Mountain Lion OSX.

I suspect that there's something wrong with the code signing. Did anyone ever experience similar issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I make a ad-hoc build I almost never use TiStudio to do this.  Here are the steps I go through when I create an Ad-Hoc:

1. Create Developer distribution profile in Member Center (make sure bundle id's match your project). Choose Ad-Hoc over app store, and be sure to include all your devices.
2. Run your titanium project, this is just to ensure there is something in the project "build" folder.
3. Goto YOUR_PROJECT/build/iphone/ and open up the XCode project.
4. Essentially from here you follow the exact method of distributing as every other XCode developer. [See this Doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html).
5. In a nutshell the above link tells you to do a "Product->Archive" then from the "Organizer" window on the "Archives" tab click the "Distribute..." button then choose the option for "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment"

As I mentioned previously, It is probably better to use the Apple workflow for this all important step in testing.